# How do you activate CSS transition hovering over a word?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want to do is enlarging a word when you hover over it. The code works, it's just that the word enlarges even if the cursor is just on the line where the word is placed.

This is my HTML code for the paragraph:

```
<p id="classic">Classic</p>
```

and this is the CSS code:

```
#classic:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Also, is there a way to do this using jQuery if you can't do it with CSS?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that illustrates your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It enlarges because the paragraph tag is display block so it takes up the entire line. You can change the p to display inline or change the tag altogether or change to float left or right. There are numerous ways to do this

Comment: If you want this effect on a word by word basis you would have to break the text into individual elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `display: inline-block;`

```css
#classic{
  display: inline-block;
}
#classic:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<p id="classic">Classic</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `p` is a block element, which extends the length of the div. Add `display:inline-block` to your element.

```
#classic{ 
    display: inline-block;
}
```